# c web server client response gets cut out by read()

Tags: c, sockets, post, webserver

I'm working on a C web server and when I send a post request to the server, only part of the post response is delivered to the server and the rest is lost. I'm pretty sure the problem isn't with the buffer size. It could be with the data not being sent in time but I can't tell. heres the code for receiving data on the server:

```
while ((readSock = read(acceptSock, recvLine, sizeof(recvLine))) > 0) {
    if (readSock < 0) {
        printf("readSock error\n");

        memset(fileDir, 0, 255);
        memset(recvLineGET1, 0, 70);
        memset(httpResponseReport, 0, 1000);
        memset(recvLineGET, 0, 60);
        memset(fileLine, 0, 1);
        memset(httpResponse, 0, 1000);

        close(acceptSock);
        return NULL;
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "%s", recvLine);

    if ((endOfPost = strstr(recvLine, "\r\n\r\n")) != NULL) {
        splitPost = strtok(endOfPost, "&");
            
        while (splitPost != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", splitPost);
            splitPost = strtok(NULL, "&");
        }

        printf("newline detected\n");
        break;
    } else if (readSock <= 0 && endOfPost == NULL) {
        perror("endOfHttpBody error");

        memset(fileDir, 0, 255);
        memset(recvLineGET1, 0, 70);
        memset(httpResponseReport, 0, 1000);
        memset(recvLineGET, 0, 60);
        memset(fileLine, 0, 1);
        memset(httpResponse, 0, 1000);

        close(acceptSock);
        return NULL;
    }

    memset(recvLine, 0, 10);
}
memset(recvLine, 0, 10);
```

Comment: Define "gets cut out". Also, is it the *request* or part of the *response* that you are talking about? Is that the code of the client or the server? Can you provide a [mre]? Please expand.

Comment: Well, you still haven't defined what you mean by "response gets cut". 1) if it's the server then it's the request, not the response... and 2) explain "cut" in more detail. Also, again, a [mre] would be better to have. In any case, doing a partial read and then `strstr(recvLine, "\r\n\r\n")` is very prone to failure as you can very well receive data split in two different reads (for example one with `\r` and the other with `\n\r\n`) and match none of them.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli For example, lets say I have a response like "username=username123&password=password123" being sent to the server for processing, what I mean by "response gets cut" is that I would receive something like: "username=usern?". Also how would I catch a ```"/r/n/r/n"``` at the end of a response if its being partially read?

Comment: (1) then it's a short read, you need one or more reads to get the rest of the data (2) store everything in a single buffer and then check, or incrementally check but still store data in one buffer only, putting all the received pieces together.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I’ll try that and update you if that works.

Comment: `while ((readSock = read(acceptSock, recvLine, sizeof(recvLine))) > 0) ...` - with a blocking socket this is assuming that the client will write-shutdown the connection after the request is done. With non-blocking socket it is assuming that data come in fast enough so that the socket will never block. Both assumptions are wrong. Instead the HTTP header needs to be first read and then to be parsed to extract the length (or to detect chunked transfer encoding). Then the body has to be read with the expected length.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on the fact that doing a call to read() with a "big enough" buffer size will actually read all of the response in one shot.
You have to call read() within a loop, until you got all of the response.
The read() call on a TCP socket gives you no guarantee of how much data you'll read. You are getting a stream of data, and the system will deliver you the data as a stream of bytes, but with no way for you to control how they are packed together.(this depends on a lot of things, deep in the network stack within the kernel,so you just can't assume anything really).
The only proper way is to loop over read() until there is no more data to read. Up to you to write your processing code in a way that can deal with not getting all of the data in one single read() call.
read() returns how many bytes have been read, so you can easily call read() again passing the buffer pointer + how many bytes have already been read so far, so that the next call to read will put bytes in your buffer right after the data that's already there. You still need to make some checks to make sure you'll not exceed the bounds of your buffer should the returned data be larger at some point.

Comment: Will you please add some line breaks? That would make it a lot easier to read.